# Postgres unpack element

Tags: python, postgresql

I've a field in a table that contains packed data sent from a lora device. The device packs it like this:

```
# LoRa payload format
# (2 Bytes for device ID, 8 float numbers: temp humid ph1 ph2 ph3 volt1 volt2 volt3)
LORA_PKG_FORMAT = "!Hffffffff"
msg = struct.pack(LORA_PKG_FORMAT, config.DEVICE_ID, temp_read, humid_read, ph1_read, ph2_read, ph3_read, volt1_read, volt2_read, volt3_read)
```

A python application on the receiving end is able to decode and unpack it like this:

```
dev_msg = base64.b64decode(rx_pkt["data"])
focus_data = struct.unpack(config.LORA_PKG_FORMAT, dev_msg)
```

The packed data in the postgres table is like this:

```
\x000141a4000042a0e3884147fd0f41477c3b4147a5303e0895213e0895213e089521
```

while the values unpacked from the python application are:

```
logging.info('Decoded payload: ' + str(focus_data))
```

> Decoded payload: (1, 20.5, 80.44439697265625, 12.499281883239746,
> 12.467829704284668, 12.477828979492188, 0.13338138163089752, 0.13338138163089752, 0.13338138163089752)

How can I achieve the same result as the struct.unpack function but with a postgres query? I need to extract every element in order to create a panel on grafana.

Comment: How about a PL/Python database function?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe from my understanding plpy would let me do queries from a python script right? I need the data decoded with with a postgres query becuse that's what grafana needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [database function in PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) and call it in an SQL query.

Database functions run inside the database and can be used in SQL.